# Link not clickable in Chrome and Firefox, but clickable in Opera and IE

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm programming a custom Theme for a wordpress blog ( http://www.ub.edu/areintra/ )
and I have a problem:
With Firefox and Chrome I can't click the two right top links ("Inici Facultat", "Inici UB"), but with IE and Opera this problem don't happens.

The CSS is not very clean but in any case, i think this problem is so strange...

any idea?

thanks in advance :) .

Comment: WordPress and CSS are two very different things. Just because you have CSS problems on a WordPress site doesn't mean this question belongs here.

Comment: It's true, but I don't know what is the best "forum" in stackexchange to make the question :p . I'm sorry.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com would probably be best.

Answer (score 2):

This is't really a WordPress related question. Anyway. It seems like your header element lies beneath your wrapper element. But I don't understand why you have structured your HTML and CSS this way, seems unnecessary. Try to change z-index for your wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

`#header, #wrapper1 { float: left; }` solves it. Anyway, it's not a wp Question.